# 504 Gateway Time-out after php fatal error

Tags: symfony, nginx, php

I'm using nginx and php-fpm to develop a symfony2 based website, under ubuntu 12.10 (yes, I know I'm using a beta OS). Everything was working out fine until, due to an error on my code, I called an unexisting function, and got the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function (....)
```

This isn't a problem (it's a bug in my code, easily fixable), but after this, no other page loads. My browser just keeps trying to load the page from the webserver, until nginx timeouts (after +- 30s, which should be some default timeout) and returns:

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

Restarting php-fpm solves the issue. Nginx logs show a timeout message, and nothing appears on php-fpm logs, even if I set them to debug level. I tried switching from fpm to fastcgi, and the same thing happens.

I've looked around, but all similar error are related to big requests/file handling, which isn't the case. All the pages on my website load in a few seconds, even under development conditions (no caching, etc).

**Edit:**

php 5.4.6

nginx 1.2.1

Comment: Hmm this might be more of a serverfault question since I think it might be the built in Nginx fcgi handler for php-fpm doing this. What fpm version/php version/nginx version is this?